# My app is not visible in google play store for samsung galaxy note 4

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, google-play

I have published an app in google play store. This app is designed for phones and I have made that it will be not visible for tablets by editing *compatible-screens* element in manifest file.

The problem is that some phones with big screen size (more than 5 inches) also can't "see" my app on google play store. For example, I can't find my app from samsung galaxy note 4 (5.7 inches, 1440 x 2560 pixels, ~515 ppi) in play store.

How I should setup my compatible-screens element that I could accurately separate phones and tablets?

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
</compatible-screens>
```

When I firstly  published my app I had the same problem with nexus 6. But I fixed it by adding these lines:

```
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
```

After that my app became available for nexus 6 and still is not available for tablets. How I could make that it would be visible also for samsung galaxy note 4?

Comment: I think the better way would be, don´t use <compatible-screens>, use <supports-screens>, here You can set the values like android:xlargeScreens="true" or android:largeScreens="true"....maybe You will have more success with that attributes...look here: http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#support-screens

Comment: Didn't helped.. After setting android:largeScreens="true", many tablets also became visible...  Probably there is no way to completely separate phones from tablets because of aliasing. note 4 by screen size is between phones and tablets... Now I am trying manually exclude devices (tablets) in google play store.

Comment: well, I think Google has to catch something up, the document in that case with different sizes is a little bit poor....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To provide support for Samsung Galaxy note 4, please add given code snippet in your manifest

```
 <compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Also, Provide at least an xxxhdpi app icon because devices can display large app icons on the launcher.